# Visual Basic descargar archivo https

Tags: vb.net, archivo, https, descarga

Usando el siguiente código:

```
Try
    Dim fileToDownload As String = "miArchivo"
    Dim downloadPath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\data\downloads\"
    Dim currDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss").ToString
    Dim downloadedFileName As String = "miArchivoDescargado" & currDate & ".xml"
    Dim downloadString = downloadPath & downloadedFileName


    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(fileToDownload, downloadString, "a", "b", True, 2500, True)


    Return True
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("No se ha podido descargar la información desde la web debido al siguiente error: " & ex.Message)
    Return False
End Try
```

Puedo descargar sin problema un archivo alojado en la ruta especificada siempre y cuando no use la conexión segura, es decir, https.

Al tratar de descargar usando httpS aparece el siguiente error:
"Se ha terminado la conexión. Error inesperado de envío."

¿Cómo valido la conexión segura usando "DownloadFile"?

Answer (score 1):

No uses Network.download usa otro como webclient, por ejemplo:

```
Dim fileToDownload As String = "miArchivo"
    Dim downloadPath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\data\downloads\"
    Dim currDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH.mm.ss").ToString
    Dim downloadedFileName As String = "miArchivoDescargado" & currDate & ".xml"
    Dim downloadString = downloadPath & downloadedFileName

     WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

//por si necesitas conectarte con algun usuario o contraseña
            CredentialCache creds = new CredentialCache(); 
            creds.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic",new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain));
//de lo contrario borra esto

            wc.Credentials = creds;
            wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent,"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;");
            //wc.Headers["Accept"] = "/";

            wc.DownloadFile(fileToDownload ,downloadString  );
```

Comment: Dos excpeciones:IOException: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto. System.Net.WebException: 'Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envío.'

Comment: El servidor es mío y hasta dónde se acepta conexiones https con alegría, qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: He probado descargando desde msdn un aspx y ha funcionado, así que es cosa del servidor :S